# Reading a file line-by-line with a timeout for lines that are taking too long?

Tags: python, perl

I have a 1.2TB file that I am running some code against, but constantly running into `OutOfMemoryError` exceptions. I ran the following two pieces of code against the file to see what was wrong:

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    count = 1
    for line in f:
        if count > 173646280:
            print line
        else:
            print count
            count += 1
```

And this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $count = 1;
while (<>) {
    print "$count\n";
    $count++;
}
```

Both of them zoom until they hit line 173,646,264, and then they just completely stop. Let me just give a quick background on the file.

I created a file called `groupBy.json`. I then processed that file with some Java code to transform the JSON objects and created a file called `groupBy_new.json`. I put `groupBy_new.json` on s3, pulled it down on another server and was doing some processing on it when I started getting OOM errors. I figured that maybe the file got corrupted when transferring to s3. I ran the above Python/Perl code on `groupBy_new.json` on both serverA (the server where it was originally at), and serverB (the server from which I pulled the file off s3), both halted at the same line. I ran then ran the above Python/Perl code on `groupBy.json`, the original file, and it also halted. I tried to recreate `groupBy_new.json` with the same code that I had used to originally create it, and ran into an OOM error.

So this is a really odd problem that is perplexing me. In short, I'd like to get rid of this line that is causing me problems. What I'm trying to do is read a file with a timeout on the line being read. If it cannot read the input line in 2 seconds or so, move on to the next line.

Comment: If you get an OOM on that line, then the line is possibly to long to be loaded into memory (many GB? depends on your machine). You cannot just skip the line because to skip the line we would need to know where that line ends, without reading the line. As a workaround you might have to read the file into a fixed-sized buffer and perform your own line splitting.

Comment: The system I am running this from has 64GB memory and I'm setting the heap size to 30GB. I'm splitting the input file now into smaller chunks. Hopefully that works. If not, I'll try running the code on a larger system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is count the number of lines until the problem line and output it - make sure you flush the output - see https://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html . Then write another program that will copy the first of this number of lines to a different file, and then read the file's input stream character by character (see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html ) until it hits a "\n" and then copy the rest of the file - either line by line or in chunks.